# How to make a rectangular pyramid in three.js r68?

Tags: javascript, three.js, geometry

I'm on r68 and I'm trying to find an example of someone creating a rectangular pyramid which I can apply THREE.MeshFaceMaterial() to, most of the examples seem fairly out of date and throw errors with my current build.

I just need to be able to

- Texturise each face
- Rotate it so the rectangular face is at the -y position

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can create a rectangular pyramid using `CylinderGeometry`.

Comment: Does it end up with 5 vertices?

Comment: Give it a try, and post your code if you have problems.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As @WestLangley stated, using a `THREE.CylinderGeometry()` to do this is the correct way, here's how I did mine

```
var geometry = new THREE.CylinderGeometry( 1, TILE_SIZE*3, TILE_SIZE*3, 4 );
var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( {color: 0xffff00 , wireframe:true} );
var cylinder = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
this.scene.add( cylinder );
```

Works perfect!

Answer (score 12):

The accepted answer works only for pyramids with a base that has equal sides. In case you want a pyramid with a rectangular foot you can do like this:

```
var geometry = new THREE.Geometry();

geometry.vertices = [
    new THREE.Vector3( 0, 0, 0 ),
    new THREE.Vector3( 0, 1, 0 ),
    new THREE.Vector3( 1, 1, 0 ),
    new THREE.Vector3( 1, 0, 0 ),
    new THREE.Vector3( 0.5, 0.5, 1 )
];

geometry.faces = [
    new THREE.Face3( 0, 1, 2 ),
    new THREE.Face3( 0, 2, 3 ),
    new THREE.Face3( 1, 0, 4 ),
    new THREE.Face3( 2, 1, 4 ),
    new THREE.Face3( 3, 2, 4 ),
    new THREE.Face3( 0, 3, 4 )
];
```

Now you have a pyramid geometry with a square base of `1 x 1` and a height of `1`. By applying a scaling matrix we can make this pyramid to any desired `width`/`length`/`height` combination:

```
var transformation = new THREE.Matrix4().makeScale( width, length, height );

geometry.applyMatrix( transformation );
```

This can also be wrapped in a custom `Pyramid` geometry class so you can use it like this:

```
new THREE.Pyramid( width, length, height );
```

Answer (score 2):

**Use ConeBufferGeometry geometry and change radialSegments to 4**

BufferGeometry are faster than normal Geometry

Other parameters you can tweak:

```
ConeBufferGeometry(radius : Float, height : Float, radialSegments : Integer, heightSegments : Integer, openEnded : Boolean, thetaStart : Float, thetaLength : Float)
```

**Result:**

[image]

**Live Demo:**

https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/geometries/ConeBufferGeometry